# Sorting two hashes into one in Python

Tags: python, hash

I have two hash `FP['NetC']` containing all cells connected to a specific net for example:

```
'net8': ['cell24', 'cell42'], 'net19': ['cell11', 'cell16', 'cell23', 'cell25', 'cell32', 'cell38']
```

and `FP['CellD_NM']` containing the x1,x0 coordinate for each cell for example:

```
{'cell4': {'Y1': 2.164, 'Y0': 1.492, 'X0': 2.296, 'X1': 2.576}, 'cell9': {'Y1': 1.895, 'Y0': 1.223, 'X0': 9.419, 'X1': 9.99}
```

I need to create a new hash (or list) that will give x0 and x1 for each cell in a spesific net. for instance:

net8: 
     cell24 {xo,x1}
     cell42 {xo,x1}
net 18:
     cell11 {xo,x1}
         ...

Here is my code

```
L1={}
L0={}
for net in FP['NetC']:

    for cell in FP['NetC'][net]:
            x1=FP['CellD_NM'][cell]['X1']
            x0=FP['CellD_NM'][cell]['X0']

            L1[net]=x1
            L0[net]=x0
print L1
print L0
```

All I got was the last value for each net.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You might like to make use of a debugger to gain a better understanding of how the code is behaving.

Comment: There may be an indentation or space/tab issue which is causing some of the statements in the inner for-loop to be executed in the outer for-loop...

Comment: You should provide some sample data, otherwise it's not easy to help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you're referring to as a "hash" is called a dictionary in Python. While dictionaries are indeed implemented as hash tables, it helps to use the right terminology!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is that you're generating `x0` and `x1` values for each `cell`, but only assigning results per `net`. Since each net has multiple cells, this overwrites all but the last values for each of them.

It looks like instead you want nested dictionaries, which you'd index like `X0[net][cell]`. Here's how you can get that:

```
L0 = {}
L1 = {}
for net, cells in FP['NetC'].items(): # use .iteritems() if you're using Python 2
    L0[net] = {}
    L1[net] = {}
    for cell in cells:
        L0[net][cell] = FP['CellD_NM'][cell]['X0']
        L1[net][cell] = FP['CellD_NM'][cell]['X1']
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your help. I started working with Python only yesterday so I did not know about the nested dictionaries. Do you have a link or a name of a book where I can read more about it, and Python in general?

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped. I don't have any especially good suggestions, as I learned Python long enough ago that I don't remember my sources very well (and they may be obsolete by now anyway). You can always start with the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org) (which includes a decent tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for net in FP['NetC']:
    L1[net] = []
    L0[net] = []
    for cell in FP['NetC'][net]:
        x1=FP['CellD_NM'][cell]['X1']
        x0=FP['CellD_NM'][cell]['X0']

        L1[net].append(x1)
        L0[net].append(x0)
```

Comment: I get : L1[net] = []
TypeError: list indices must be integers

Comment: @Yul: Did you keep your initial definitions of `L1 = {}` (and same for L2)? This method will use `L1, L0` as dictionaries using `FP['NetC']` as the index to a list of the `x1,x0` values.